# Virtualbox & network connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I want to create server for controlling tv from outside of home. For doing this i had an idea like this:

On ubnutu machine i will have VNC and using it i will connect from outside. On server i would have android emulator with working application from goolge play, for controlling tv. My main problem is:

Ubuntu server and TV are connected to same network: 192.168.0.x while android emulator (genymotion) is connected to ubuntu server by virtualbox network 192.168.51.x; I need to have android emulator and TV in same network to be able to use app to control TV. Question is: how to do it ?

regards
J

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to change the VBOX network settings. I just dismantled my virtual box host so I do not have access to the screen, but if my memory serves me right it is done in Network selecting Bridged Adapter, and ticking off Cable connect. Virtual box is going to pick up your host's address space and subnet and asigns a dynamic address, so all three are going to be on 192.168.0.x